# Install apache on Linux silent avoiding AH00558

Tags: linux, apache, bash

I'm writing a bash script which installs Apache2 on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).

```
echo "Check if Apache is installed"

dpkg -p "apache2" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "Apache2 is not installed"
    echo "Apache2 installing"
    apt-get -q -y install apache2 > /dev/null
    echo "Apache2 installed"
else
    echo "Apache2 is already installed"
fi
```

The script should be silent, only the 'echos' should be shown. But I get:

```
Check if Apache is installed
Apache2 is not installed
Apache2 installing
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Apache2 installed
```

I know how to fix AH00558 after installation, but I want to suppress the warning while installation.

What is the solution?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `2>&1` from your call to `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: the order of redirection

It works with

```
apt-get -y install apache2 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the stderr stream to `/dev/NULL`

```
apt-get -q -y install apache2 2>&1 1> /dev/null
```

This will make you stdout and stderr redirecting to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I still get the same warning.

Comment: @user3656083 Try in terminal while running that script. `./.sh 2>/dev/null`.